# c++11 type_traits: different result in INTEL 2013 and GCC 4.7.2

Tags: c++11, type-traits

For the following class, INTEL 2013 (update 3) and GCC 4.7.2 give different `type_traits` results. Which one is right?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;

private:
    double t_;
};

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << "is_trivial<A>         : " << is_trivial<A>::value << endl;
    cout << "is_compound<A>        : " << is_compound<A>::value << endl;
    cout << "is_pod<A>             : " << is_pod<A>::value << endl;
    cout << "is_standard_layout<A> : " << is_standard_layout<A>::value << endl;
    cout << "is_literal_type<A>    : " << is_literal_type<A>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

INTEL output:

```
is_trivial<A>         : true
is_compound<A>        : true
is_pod<A>             : false
is_standard_layout<A> : true
is_literal_type<A>    : false
```

GCC output:

```
is_trivial<A>         : true
is_compound<A>        : true
is_pod<A>             : true
is_standard_layout<A> : true
is_literal_type<A>    : true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say GCC is correct. `is_pod` is true if it's both `is_trivial` and `is_standard_layout`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod . Intel compiler doesn't comply with this. `is_literal_type` should also be true since all the conditions seem valid for `A`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_literal_type

Comment: Hmmm, is a defaulted constructor a `constexpr` constructor?  An implicitly-provided one would be, but I'm not sure the explicitly defaulted one is, if not explicitly declared `constexpr`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Why should it differ? Both are computable at compile time.

Comment: Because when you're explicitly defaulting it, you have the opportunity to explicitly use the `constexpr` keyword, and so if you don't do so, the compiler maybe should assume you didn't want it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hmm, assuming it's true, why would you assume the opposite for implicit constructor? As far as I know the `constexpr` is never implied if not specified explicitly. I'm also not sure that statement "*all of its constructor calls and initializers for nonstatic data members are constant expressions*" is equal to `constexpr`.

Comment: Not assuming.  The Standard says in 12.1 that "If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a `constexpr` constructor, the implicitly-defined default constructor is `constexpr`."  And I'm looking at a different requirement for literal types, namely: "it is an aggregate type or has at least one `constexpr` constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor"

Comment: It surely isn't an aggregate, because it has a private non-static data member.  Therefore it needs a `constexpr` constructor or a `constexpr` constructor template, excluding copy and move constructors.

Comment: Finally, it looks like an explicitly *declared* default constructor is implicitly *defined*, and therefore is made `constexpr` by the above rule.